# how can i make move a letter in c like an animation

Tags: c

i want to give the output like the letter 'O' is moving towards the middle stump from opposite end of the pitch like ball travelling. but i unable to get that output. so how can i correct this to get my output

```
    #include<stdio.h>

void ball();
int i=0,j=0;;
char ground[22][17]=
           {
           "       _ _     ",
           "      | | |    ",
           "      | | |    ",
           " _____|_|_|____",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           "|               |",
           " _______________"};

int main()
{
 for(i=0;i<22;i++)
{
  printf("\n");
  for(j=0;j<17;j++)
 {
   printf("%c",ground[i][j]);
 }
 ground[i][9]= O;
 printf("%c",ground[i][9]);
  ground[i][9]= ;
  printf("%c",ground[i][9]);

}return 0;}
```

Comment: It's not possible to "animate" anything using plain standard C. Either you have to use special console-formatting codes or libraries, or just "redraw" *everything* when you need to update a single character.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude to be fair, OP says "like an animation".